# $[0,5]$ is not compact with the Sorgenfrey topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Show that in the Sorgenfrey topology $[0,5]$ is not compact. Justify your answer.

Here is my shot at an answer. Could anyone please knock it down/improve it/help with the correct answer?

> Consider $G_n = [0,4 + \frac{n-1}{n})$ where $n \in \Bbb{N}$. Then
>    $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n = [0,5)$$
>    So $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n = [0,5) \not\ni 5$$
>    Therefore $[0,5]$ is not compact in the Sorgenfrey topology.

Comment: Can you include the definition of the Sorgenfrey topology in your question? I am not familiar with it. Also, the collection $$\left\{\left[0,4+\frac{n-1}{n}\right): n\in \Bbb{N} \right\}$$ isn't a cover of $[0,5]$ to begin with anyway, so you haven't disproved or proved the compactness of $[0,5]$.

Comment: Nameless, I am confused why that would not be right. 4 + (n-1)/n tends toward 5 as n approaches infinity, right?

Comment: I think your equality is correct.

Comment: My bad, it is right. When I first read it, I thought it goes way above $5$.

Comment: @graydad, apparently it is the "lower limit topology".

Comment: @Nameless ah okay. I have some experience with this

Comment: Add the open set $\{5\}$ to the cover. This is open in $[0,5]$ in the Sorgenfrey line (as it equals $[5,6) \cap [0,5]$, so is open in the subspace topology). Then you have a countable open (!) cover of $[0,5]$ (in relatively open subsets) that does not have a finite subcover.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the collection of sets you have described isn't an open cover of $[0,5]$. By definition, $\mathcal{C} = \{C_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in \lambda}$ is an open cover of $[0,5]$ if each $C_\alpha$ is an open set AND $$[0,5] \subset \bigcup_{\alpha \in \lambda}C_\alpha$$ You have a collection $\left\{\left[0,4+\frac{n-1}{n}\right): n \in \Bbb{N} \right\}$ but all you have shown is that $$[0,5] \not\subset \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb{N}}\left[0,4+\frac{n-1}{n}\right)$$ which is to say you proved that  $\left\{\left[0,4+\frac{n-1}{n}\right): n \in \Bbb{N} \right\}$ is not an open cover of $[0,5]$. Instead, try the collection  $\left\{\left[0,4+\frac{n-1}{n}\right): n \in \Bbb{N} \right\} \cup [5,6)$. It should be clear that $$[0,5] \subset \left(\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb{N}}\left[0,4+\frac{n-1}{n}\right)\right) \cup [5,6)$$ and now you just have to prove that finitely many elements of $\left\{\left[0,4+\frac{n-1}{n}\right): n \in \Bbb{N} \right\} \cup [5,6)$ will not cover $[0,5]$.

Comment: Thanks, graydad. A quick question for you before I fully dive deep in your explanation: should the interval be [5,6) in order for it to be open Sorgenfry?

Comment: Yes you are correct! My mistake :) Although ending the interval at $6$ was arbitrary. Any $x>5$ will work

Comment: Ok, thanks! Now, as for how to show that a finitely many elements is not a sufficient cover, a proof by contradiction?

Comment: That would work. I would probably go direct personally

Comment: How about this:

Continue by Contradiction
 
Suppose $\exists m \in \N:\ds{\bigcup_{n=1}^{m}}G_n \ni [0,5]$.
 
Then $\ds{\bigcup_{n=1}^{m}}G_n = [0,4 + \frac{m-1}{m}) \cup [5,6)=[0,6)$.
 
This implies that $\frac{m-1}{m} = 1 \Rightarrow m-1 = m$

Comment: That looks reasonable, but I would drop the notion of $G_n$ and try to be more general. Like let $K \subset \Bbb{N}$ be any finite index, and consider $K_s = \sup(K)$. Then $$\bigcup_{i \in K}\left[0,\frac{i-1}{i}\right) = \left[0,\frac{K_s-1}{K_s}\right)$$ Since $$[0,5]\backslash \left[0 \frac{K_s-1}{K_s}\right) = \left[\frac{K_s-1}{K_s},5\right]$$ then obviously $$\left\{\left[0,\frac{i-1}{i}\right)\right\}_{i \in K}$$ is not a finite subcover, nor is $$\left\{\left[0,\frac{i-1}{i}\right)\right\}_{i \in K} \bigcup [5,6)$$ Thus, no finite collection of open cover elements is a finite subcover

Comment: Thank you, graydad! I will have to digest that a bit.

Comment: Of course! I love the covering properties. Let me know if any of it is unclear